# What is wrong with this Ejabberd roster response?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to intergrate the Adium Jabber Client with the ejabberd server with a modified roster module. The client sends the following request;

```
<iq type='get' id='purpled07bdf7f'>
       <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>
</iq>
```

And my server sends this response.

```
<iq from='17479996@localhost' to='17479996@localhost/Usman-Ismails-Mac-mini' id='purpled07bdf7f' type='result'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'>
          <item subscription='both' name='Name' jid='test@localhost'>
                <group>Contacts</group>
         </item>
     </query>
</iq>
```

The docs say this should work but I don't see a friend in the friends list on the client. Any ideas?

```
Example: Client requests current roster from server:

<iq from='juliet@example.com/balcony' type='get' id='roster_1'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>
</iq>
Example: Client receives roster from server:

<iq to='juliet@example.com/balcony' type='result' id='roster_1'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'>
    <item jid='romeo@example.net'
          name='Romeo'
          subscription='both'>
      <group>Friends</group>
    </item>
    <item jid='mercutio@example.org'
          name='Mercutio'
          subscription='from'>
      <group>Friends</group>
    </item>
    <item jid='benvolio@example.org'
          name='Benvolio'
          subscription='both'>
      <group>Friends</group>
    </item>
  </query>
</iq>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Adium, make sure you are showing your offline contacts.  Look on the View menu and make sure "Hide Certain Contacts" and "Hide Offline Contacts" aren't both checked.

Answer (score 0):

My memory is hazy with this, but IIRC - have you registered your presence?

Comment: I think presence comes after you have a friends list.